# Docker compose libstdc++.so.6 GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found

Tags: c++, c, node.js, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

When running `docker-compose up` in my node directory, I get

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /app/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node)
```

But I definitely have the glib:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
```

I tried doing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/164296/glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found but I get the same error. I have no idea how to resolve this and can't find a solution anywhere else.

This is on Ubuntu 16.04 if it matters.

Comment: Did you try `npm install --build-from-source bcrypt` inside the container? Most likely the pre-built versions of the addon are built on a newer/older system, but compiling from source locally *should* always work to avoid ABI issues.

Comment: Nope, just giving me the same error.

Comment: Working after I removed bcrypt then ran this command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some node addons on npm use [`node-pre-gyp`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp) to provide the ability to download pre-compiled addon binaries so that you don't need a compiler installed to use it (mainly useful on Windows, where it is usually more difficult to get a build environment set up).

For these kinds of addons, you can specify a [`--build-from-source` command line option](https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp#options) to tell `node-pre-gyp` to always compile locally instead of downloading one of the pre-compiled addon binaries.

By installing the addon with this flag, you can avoid such errors when the pre-compiled addon binaries are compiled on older/newer machines that utilize different glibc ABIs.